# Identify date format of string entered by the user in php laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-4

I have this search functionality that gets the users input and sorts it according to date created and date uploaded.

What I have done so far is to determine whether the input is in `M-y-d` format but the specs changed so the user can input a string. Then I should check whether or not it is a valid date format, then get its date format to use it in my sort.

I am at a loss on how to do it. Any ideas?

Here is my current code

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('M - d - Y', Input::get('searchb')) !== FALSE) 
        {
            // it's a date
            // dd('its a date');
            $sampledate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('M - d - Y', Input::get('searchb'))->format('Y-m-d');
            $srvc = $srvc->where('r.created_at' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sampledate.'%');
            if($usrRole!='Admin' || $usrRole!='Analytics-Sups')
            {
                $temp = $temp->where('r.created_at' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sampledate.'%');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow, that is a long sentence.

Comment: Instead of passing string why dont you pass date by using datepicker of specific format, it will solve your problem such that you dont require to compare date in controller.

Answer (score -1):

You could use PHP strtotime function to convert any kind of date input into the needed format.

```
if (strtotime(Input::get('searchb')) !== false) {
    // Valid date
    $sampledate = date('M - d - y',strtotime(Input::get('searchb')));

    // Prepare DB search...
}
```